# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'values' heatmap

Tags: python, dataframe, heatmap, geopandas, folium

I'm trying to plot a heatmap using this code:

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import HeatMap

max_Count = (dataM['count'].max())
hmap = folium.Map(location=[53.192838, 8.197006], zoom_start=7,)

hm_wide = HeatMap( list(zip(dataM.latitude.values, dataM.longitude.values, dataM.count.values)), 
                   min_opacity=0.2,
                   max_val=max_Count,
                   radius=17, blur=15, 
                   max_zoom=1, 
                 )

hmap.add_child(hm_wide)
```

the dataframe looks like that:

```
                     station    count   latitude    longitude   city
Time                    
2021-05-01 00:00:00 02-MI-JAN-N 11.0    52.5139 13.41780    Berlin
2021-05-01 00:00:00 24-MH-ALB   0.0     52.4925 13.55850    Berlin
2021-05-01 00:00:00 23-TK-KAI   1.0     52.4573 13.51870    Berlin

... ... ... ... ... ...

2021-09-09 23:45:00 50801_Amalienstr    0.0 53.1390 8.22225 Oldenburg
```

but i'm getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-c1b7a410c325> in <module>
      5 hmap = folium.Map(location=[53.192838, 8.197006], zoom_start=7,)
      6 
----> 7 hm_wide = HeatMap( list(zip(dataM.latitude.values, dataM.longitude.values, dataM.count.values)), 
      8                    min_opacity=0.2,
      9                    max_val=max_Count,

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Any idea about the reason behind it and how can it be solved?
Thank you

UPDATE:
I've used `dataM['latitude'], dataM['longitude'], dataM['count']` and it works :))

Comment: Probably that means that you should replace `dataM.latitude.values` by `dataM.latitude().values` , the same with longitude or more probably count

Comment: The error message is quite clear: you are trying to access the property `values` of `dataM.latitude`. However, the latter is a function or a method (as indicated by the error text). You'd probably need to use `dataM.latitude().values`. Same probably goes for the `longitude` method.

Comment: when i try it using ..latitude() ... i get this error : TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
the strange thing for me , is i'm using the same code for another dataframe and it works pretty good without ()  @AmitaiIrron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import HeatMap

max_Count = (dataM['count'].max())
hmap = folium.Map(location=[53.192838, 8.197006], zoom_start=7,)

hm_wide = HeatMap( list(zip(dataM['latitude'], dataM['longitude'], dataM['count'])), 
                   min_opacity=0.2,
                   max_val=max_Count,
                   radius=17, blur=15, 
                   max_zoom=1, 
                 )

hmap.add_child(hm_wide)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).